# How can I use bootstrap grid layout while accounting for scrollbar width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, scrollbar

Please take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/c8MBg/2/ which I made based on [twitter bootstrap scaffolding examples](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

```
<div class="span9 scroll-sucker">
<div class="row show-grid">
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span4">4</div>
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span5">5</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
    <div title="" data-original-title="" class="span9">9</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap grid system to layout some component in my UI while keeping the content responsive. The problem arises when the grid container gets a scrollbar. For example in this case my container of size 9 can fit 9 X span1 div in a row as expected when it does not have a scrollbar. However, when it has a vertical scrollbar (on any desktop browser) it can only fit 8 x span1 divs in a row.

```
.scroll-sucker {
  overflow: scroll;   
}
```

[image]

I can think of many different hacky ways to account for the size of scrollbar, but what is the bootstrap way or a recommended way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard "bootstrap way" to do this... The responsiveness that bootstrap provides is re-sizing the span elements as you make the window smaller, and then when the window gets really narrow it stacks them all vertically. I don't think it was really built with having scroll bars added to the spans in mind.

I am curious as to why there is a scroll bar on the span. In your example if you create a div *around* the span and put the scroll bar on that it works probably as you would expect. Here's your jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/c8MBg/5/

```
<div class="scroll-sucker">
<div class="span9 ">
<div class="row show-grid">
    stuff....
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit also typically `span{#}` elements are always within `row` elements. Also in conclusion, I'd say there is no standard way and if this is something you really need you'll just have to make it work... (hacky it may be)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I agree with you that scrollbars should not usually appear with a responsive grid like this. But in a project I came across a bug where in some edge cases scroll bar is shown. Anyhow, your solution seem very reasonable.